# How to fix the replace method error on Android?

Tags: android, tabs, compiler-errors, android-actionbar

I am creating Android application with action bar tab all the code if perfect but I have a problem with the replace method for the fragment. how to fix this error?

the system display:

> **The method replace(int, Fragment) in the type FragmentTransaction is not applicable for the arguments (int, Fragment)**

## StartActivity.java

```
package com.devlebactionbartab;

import android.net.wifi.p2p.WifiP2pManager.ActionListener;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.drm.DrmStore.Action;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class StartActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);


        ActionBar actionbar  = getActionBar();
        actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionbar.setTitle("Tabbed Layout");


        ActionBar.Tab Frag1Tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment1");
        ActionBar.Tab Frag2Tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment2");
        ActionBar.Tab Frag3Tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment3");
        ActionBar.Tab Frag4Tab = actionbar.newTab().setText("Fragment4");

        Fragment fragment1 = new Fragment_1();
        Fragment fragment2 = new Fragment_2();
        Fragment fragment3 = new Fragment_3();
        Fragment fragment4 = new Fragment_4();

        Frag1Tab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment1));
        Frag2Tab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment2));
        Frag3Tab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment3));
        Frag4Tab.setTabListener(new MyTabsListener(fragment4));

        actionbar.addTab(Frag1Tab);
        actionbar.addTab(Frag2Tab);
        actionbar.addTab(Frag3Tab);
        actionbar.addTab(Frag4Tab);
    }


class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener{

    public Fragment fragment;

    //constractor
    public MyTabsListener (Fragment fragment){

        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment);
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.start, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
 android.app.FragmentTransaction.replace(int id,android.app.Fragment fragment);
```

Your method is looking for a Fragment that comes from android.app.Fragment, you have imported android.support.v4.app.Fragment. My sugguestion is you import your FragmentTransaction from v4 support as well.

steps:

**DELETE**: `import android.app.FragmentTransaction;`

**ADD**: `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;`

The go to eclipse->project->clean -> clean all.

[v4 support FragmentTransaction](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentTransaction.html)

Comment: @ wtsang02 i did as you said i import import **android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;** but still the same error

Comment: delete both FragmentTransaction and Fragment imports, add the v4 imports, clean.

Comment: what do you mean by add v4 imports , clean ?? i tried to just import android.v4.app but it give me an error

Comment: added the steps in answer.

Comment: i will edit my question and add what i tried to do with the import maybe you will be able to help me

Comment: i did all what you said i delete and add and clean but still get the same dam problemmmm without any change

Answer (score 3):

I had same problem because i was using getFragmentManager().  If you use getSupportFragmentManager(). it would solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing newer fragment support types with support classes. Replace these lines:

```
import android.app.Fragment;
```

with    `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

`import android.app.FragmentManager;`
with    `import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;`

Then extend android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity instead of Activity and change calls like **getFragmentManager() with getSupportFragmentManager()** and similarly for other methods that you might be using.

Comment: `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment` and other all fixed it for me when i tried to getItem on fragment adapter